# How to use Yii MVC from other scripts? (Not only from index.php)

Tags: php, yii

**Hello!**

With help of Yii GII I generated a controller+view:

*/Controllers/XmlWorkerController.php + /views/XmlWorker/index.php.*

There is a simplest code in /views/XmlWorker/index.php:

```
<?
echo 'Hello, world';
```

There is also a file index2.php, just after the standart index.php, in the same directory.

In some reason it is necessary to call in browser: `http://localhost/index2.php` and see just
'Hello, world!". No standard Yii header/footer at all.

There is some code in my index2.php:

```
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/yii/framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';

defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config);
list($controller) = Yii::app()->createController('XmlWorker');
$controller->actionIndex();
```

But as a result I see "Hello, world!" between Yii standart header/footer. It is necessary to see this sentence in a clear white browser window.

**How can I arrive such goal?**

P.S. *Of course, task is simplified. What is the real reason to do it?
Lets say, I have two clients. First client wants to call index2.php (without any parameters) and gets some information in XML format. Second client wants to call index3.php (without any parameters) and gets some other information in HTML format. So, it is necessary to provide two different entrance points for them.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also simply set `$this->layout = false;` in your controller where you don't want any layout to be rendered. No need for another entry script.

**Edit:**
I don't really understand why there should be no parameters.
But you can do it even with one entry script, using different controller actions. Or by routing calls to different actions. Or use `mod_rewrite` to internally rewrite the url with parameters, which leds to your controller/action with parameters.

I would maybe go with the rewrite thing, it should be nice an clean.

Comment: Thanks! But I need another entry script because every client wants his own function and wants to call script without any parameters. Is it a good practice to use different entry scripts with Yii?

Comment: No I don't think it's a good practice. It can lead to confusion, which script to use. Also there might be no protection to use another entry script `index2.php` when someone was intended to use `index.php` and so on. It could work though.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want different entry points. You can render a page without a layout (header and footer) with the renderPartial function in the controller.

In the controller it says something like

```
$this->render('index');
```

Make that

```
$this->renderPartial('index');
```